# Custom initializer with objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
Class UserLaunch: Object{

var launch: Class1
var payload: Class2

init(launch: Class1, payload: Class2){
    self.launch = launch
    self.payload = payload
}
```

What is the best way to create custom initializer for Realm object? (This one isn't working, because Realm wants default init() method)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can give some default value to the properties this should work (it works for me at least):

```
class UserLaunch: Object{

    dynamic var launch: Class1 = Class1() //or some other default value
    dynamic var payload: Class2 = Class2() //or some other default value

    convenience init(launch: Class1, payload: Class2){
        self.init()
        self.launch = launch
        self.payload = payload
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the properties should also be marked as `dynamic`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I tried like this , dynamic var links: Links? = Links()  it gives an error "Variable used within its own initial value"